# python-requests returning unicode Exception message (or how to set requests locale)

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to figure out how to get proper english/ascii error message from a failes `requests.get`. for some reason (probably being working with a hebrew locale), I get a jibrish unicode error message. I can deocde the message and display it correctly in hebrew, but I really prefer (for various reasons) that the Exception error text would be in english.

checking [Requests Exception source code](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/exceptions.py) doesn't even lead me in the right direction, Since I seem to be I'm getting a different exception:
`(10060, some encoded error text,')`
and the class is: `<class 'socket.error'>`.

So I guess we are probably looking at a `socket.error` from [socket lib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.error). At least as far as I can tell from parsing the Exception args (I can't raise the exception directly, only while running the app, where I do a smelly `except Exception as e` and parse `e.args` and `e.message`).

**EDIT:** this is the results I get from parsing `e.args`, `e.message`, `e.__class__`

`(10060, '\xfe\xfe\xf0\xe9\xf1\xe9\xe5\xef \xe7\xe9\xe1\xe5\xf8 \xf0\xeb\xf9\xec \xee\xe0\xe7\xf8 \xf9\xe4\xf6\xe3 \xe4\xee\xe7\xe5\xe1\xf8 \xec\xe0 \xe4\xe2\xe9\xe1 \xeb\xf8\xe0\xe5\xe9 \xec\xe0\xe7\xf8 \xfa\xf7\xe5\xf4\xfa \xe6\xee\xef,'), message: , class: <class 'socket.error'>`

the string is encoded 'windows-1255' and decodes to (hebrew):

> ‏‏ניסיון חיבור נכשל מאחר שהצד המחובר לא הגיב כראוי לאחר תקופת זמן,

tranlates to: "connection attempt failed since the connected side didn't respond properly after a time period"

the code raising the Exception:

```
try:
    print ("parsing json from:", srvstr)
    getjson = requests.get(srvstr, params=params, auth=(user, password), verify=ssl)
    print('url:', getjson.url)
except Exception as e:
    args = ", ".join(args)
    details = 'args: %s, message: %s, class: %s' % (args, e.message, e.__class__)
```

So:

how do I set the locale so that requests (or the underlying socket lib if my guess is correct) would return an english/Ascii error message?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please supply at least some code, and preferably a url.

Comment: @Udi added, missed that while writing the question.. Thanks for the headsup

Comment: Can you drop the try block and send a complete traceback as raised from .get() ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `os.strerror`, but it would probably return nothing or the same non-English string.

This hard-coded English was scraped from here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819124

```
ENGLISH_WINDOWS_SOCKET_MESSAGES = {
    10004: "Interrupted function call.",
    10013: "Permission denied.",
    10014: "Bad address.",
    10022: "Invalid argument.",
    10024: "Too many open files.",
    10035: "Resource temporarily unavailable.",
    10036: "Operation now in progress.",
    10037: "Operation already in progress.",
    10038: "Socket operation on nonsocket.",
    10039: "Destination address required.",
    10040: "Message too long.",
    10041: "Protocol wrong type for socket.",
    10042: "Bad protocol option.",
    10043: "Protocol not supported.",
    10044: "Socket type not supported.",
    10045: "Operation not supported.",
    10046: "Protocol family not supported.",
    10047: "Address family not supported by protocol family.",
    10048: "Address already in use.",
    10049: "Cannot assign requested address.",
    10050: "Network is down.",
    10051: "Network is unreachable.",
    10052: "Network dropped connection on reset.",
    10053: "Software caused connection abort.",
    10054: "Connection reset by peer.",
    10055: "No buffer space available.",
    10056: "Socket is already connected.",
    10057: "Socket is not connected.",
    10058: "Cannot send after socket shutdown.",
    10060: "Connection timed out.",
    10061: "Connection refused.",
    10064: "Host is down.",
    10065: "No route to host.",
    10067: "Too many processes.",
    10091: "Network subsystem is unavailable.",
    10092: "Winsock.dll version out of range.",
    10093: "Successful WSAStartup not yet performed.",
    10101: "Graceful shutdown in progress.",
    10109: "Class type not found.",
    11001: "Host not found. No such host is known.",
    11002: "Nonauthoritative host not found.",
    11003: "This is a nonrecoverable error.",
    11004: "Valid name, no data record of requested type.",
}
```

(For future scrapers: The following xpaths were used: `//div[@id="MT1"]//h3` and `following-sibling::ul/li`)

Comment: Seems too much trouble, I'm sure there a way to override locale detection